# Delay ajax success, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got stuck on something simple. When I make an ajax request, by some how it doesn't have enough time to make assignment to `combonews` variable:

```
jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "People.aspx/LoadComboNews",
            data: "{\"id\":" + usrid + "}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
                combonews = '';
                setTimeout(function () { combonews = eval(msg.d); }, 500);
                //combonews = eval(msg.d);

            }
    });
```

tried to add setTimeout as shown, but still when I want to alert `combonews`  it's empty.
When I alert `msg.d` it's always have data ready. 
Is there a way to extend the time for `combonews = eval(msg.d);` to be perfomed?

**UPDATE:**

When I run it by binding to button click event, the assignment works fine

**---------------------------------------**

**UPDATE2**

```
function lcombo() {
    jQuery('#combostart ~ option').remove();
    //setTimeout((function () {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "People.aspx/LoadComboNews",
            data: "{\"id\":" + usrid + "}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            complete: function (msg) {
                // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
                combonews = '';
                //setTimeout(function () { combonews = eval(msg.d); }, 500);
                combonews = JSON.parse(msg.d);

            }
        });
        //combonews = eval(combonews);
        //alert(combonews);
        jQuery(".chzn-select").chosen();
        jQuery(".chzn-select-deselect").chosen({ allow_single_deselect: true });
        var str = "";
        if (combonews.length > 0)
            for (var i in combonews) {
                str += "<option value='" + combonews[i][0] + "'>" + combonews[i][1] + "</option>";
            }
        jQuery("#combooptions").append(str);
        jQuery("#combooptions").val(draftid);
        jQuery("#combooptions").trigger("liszt:updated"); 
}
```

and then I load lcombo() function. which works on click, but doesn't in some other consequences (I mean doesn't load the message to combonews)

THanks you

Comment: Yes it does work fine when I click, but i need it to be performed automatically

Comment: I am saying. If you look in firebug, does the AJAX query come back ok WITHOUT it being on click. Basically, does the ajax work ok (minus the data actually getting put somewhere).

Comment: You should use `JSON.parse()`, not `eval()`.

Comment: Where are you calling alert?

Comment: @Jeff Shaver yes id does come back when I alert(msg.d) Slaks i use alert outside the given

Comment: I am a little confused on the `eval()` call. Why use eval

Comment: I've got $1000 riding on the fact that you are alert()-ing your message before your AJAX request is complete. Your post does not show at what point in the code you are calling an alert() so we have no idea. Best thing to do is to post a minimal jsFiddle and link to it.

Comment: I will Update my question

Comment: @Jeff Shaver Actually I should have used JSON.parse. Thre reson is that, I have a jason type message

Comment: For simplicity sake, take all the code AFTER your ajax request, and drop it all inside your complete function. You were trying to do something with the variable "combonews" before your ajax request was complete.

Comment: @Adam isn't the setTimeout might help somehow ?

Comment: You cannot rely on setTimeout when it comes to ajax because the response from the server might come back in 50ms, or it might take 5s and you have no control over this. This is why we use callback functions when working with aysnchronous ajax calls - like "complete"

Comment: Also, don't listen to them below. Change it back to `success`. Complete will fire regardless of your ajax request getting a 200 OK response from the server.

Comment: If @Adam's solution to move the code inside the success event handler works (which I believe it will), it should be moved to an answer and marked correct.

Comment: guys while I was testing the code this is what happened : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15304087/js-file-content-disappeared-in-visual-studio-2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Adam that was the only solution I found, and I am making your comment as an answer

For simplicity sake, take all the code AFTER your ajax request, and drop it all inside your complete function. You were trying to do something with the variable "combonews" before your ajax request was complete. – Adam

But instead of `complete` I used `success`

thanks for everyone